# wput upload multiple files without recreating directory tree on destination

Tags: linux, ftp

I am trying to find a way to upload batch of files from one server to another by cron few times a day and wput seems like best and easiest option to use.

It works so far fine, but problem is that wput always recreating directory tree on destination. So here is command i use.

```
wput -u /var/www/clients/client1/web/parser/*.json ftp://username:password@remoteserver/web/
```

So this is supposed to upload all the files inside directory `/parser/` and files that have `.json` extension.

This works very nice, except:

When it upload the files to remote server it uploads whole directory tree and instead of having a list of files inside `/web/` folder on remote server the files are uploaded with all directories from source server

Instead having this:

```
/web/file1.json
/web/file2.json
/web/file3.json
/web/file4.json
```

I have this

```
/web/var/www/clients/client1/web/parser/file1.json
/web/var/www/clients/client1/web/parser/file2.json
/web/var/www/clients/client1/web/parser/file3.json
/web/var/www/clients/client1/web/parser/file4.json
```

How can i prevent wput to upload whole directory tree on remoteserver?

Comment: According to the [man page](http://wput.sourceforge.net/wput.1.html) there is a `−−no−directories` switch. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes i did, i was thinking it would work with -nd but than i get bunch of errors and it fails to upload files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem is that `wput` is always recreating the directory tree on the destination

You need to use the `−−basename=path` option:

> This option causes `Wput` to snip path from all input−files when they are connected to the URL. `wput /usr/share/doc.tgz ftp://host/` would create `ftp://host//usr/share/doc.tgz`, whereas specifying `/usr/share/` as basename will result in `ftp://host/doc.tgz` being created.

Source [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/wput.1.html)

Try the following command:

```
wput --basename=/var/www/clients/client1/web/parser -u /var/www/clients/client1/web/parser/*.json ftp://username:password@remoteserver/web/
```

Comment: That's it, worked like a charm. I didn't understood what basename=path do, i tried few different variations but failed in properly making command. Thanks for this.